# Replacing tomcat server.xml in Elastic Beanstalk using .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I'm trying to replace the server.xml file of my Tomcat server in an Elastic Beanstalk environment. To achieve this, I created the .ebextensions folder in the root of my source bundle and added the new server.xml and a file server.config containing the following:

```
container_commands:
  replace-config:
    command: cp .ebextensions/server.xml /usr/share/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

However, during the build process, I encountered the following error:

> 2023-07-31 16:47:28,043 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD
> FAILED!------------------------ 2023-07-31 16:47:28,043 [ERROR]
> Unhandled exception during build: Command replace-config failed
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init",
> line 176, in 
> worklog.build(metadata, configSets)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 137, in build
> Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 564, in build
> self.run_config(config, worklog)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line
> 576, in run_config
> CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py",
> line 276, in build
> self._config.commands)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line
> 127, in apply
> raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)

I also attempted using sudo in the cp command, but it didn't work either.

Permissions to the file:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root tomcat   8611 Jul 19 20:18 server.xml

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to replace the server.xml file successfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly. Just double confirm your destination path "/usr/share/tomcat/conf/server.xml" is correct.

Depending on your ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat version, this path will vary. As of writing, latest Tomcat 10 has a path of "/etc/tomcat10/server.xml".